# Windows 10 - Files missing from desktop suddenly after explorer crash

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, desktop

Today on Windows 10 Home, explorer.exe seemed to crash (entire screen turned white, all windows closed, then the desktop slowly reappeared and the taskbar was repopulated). Afterwards, a number of files and folders were missing AND my hard drive storage went up by roughly the amount of the files (they seem to have been actually deleted). This all happened right before my eyes: there was no deletion and the files are not in the recycle bin.

I have seen questions pertaining to missing files on the Desktop, but they all relate to an Upgrade (no upgrade here), and the common solution is to run checkdisk and to check the C:\users\\appdata\temp folder, but checkdisk returns no errors and the files are not in the temp folder.

This is very troubling. One strange thing I noticed was I was listening to an audio file from one of the folders containing the (now) missing files. The audio file that was playing is the only one left in that folder (it was not deleted). I would guess that if there was a mass delete it would have thrown a warning saying that the file was in use, but it did not.

*The files are not hidden! As I mentioned before it appears that the storage for the files was also reclaimed. I am baffled and have no indication this will not happen again.

Comment: Have you tried recovery software, like Recuva (deep scan mode)? Of course, install such software on a different partition and don't try to restore to the original partition.

Comment: For now I've found an adequate backup of the data and can move on. Still not sure what the problem was, but I have obvious doubts that this will be resolved (in terms of prevention in the future) due to the bizarre nature of the problem. I was going to delete the question if it did not receive an answer but now there is an upvote, so maybe I'm not the only one.